# How to use large .npy file for training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm building a classifier. My data is saved in .npy file which is over 40GB big, so obviously it's hard to fit it in the memory. I found that using mmap_mode when loading fle may help, but I'm not sure how to use it for training. Currently I am using the following method:

```
data_train_np = np.load('./train.npy',mmap_mode='r')
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data_train_np, labels))
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

I am training using fit(), but I think this does not feed all the data to the model. Anyone can help with that or tell what is the correct way to use numpy data in mmap_mode for training?

Comment: For data that size I would read the file into a dask array. If you are running this on a single machine you are going to have problems all the way up and down stream but dask will get you by loading the data.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to do this.

I will assume that the transformations you are doing to the images to get the final matrix is very expensive, and that it's not desirable to do the pre-processing on the data loading. If this is not the case, you might benefit from reading the [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images) relevant to image processing.

I suggest you use a python generator to read the data, and to use `tf.data` to create a data pipeline to feed these `.npy` files to your model. The basic idea is very simple. you use a wrapper to ingest data from a generator that will read the files as needed. The relevant documentation and examples are [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#consuming_python_generators).

Now, once you get that working, I think it would be a good idea for you to [optimize](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance) your pipeline, especially if you're planning to train in multiple GPUs or multiple computers.